# How to flip coordinate system in Pyglet?

Tags: coordinates, pyglet

Is there any way I can flip the coordinate system in Pyglet vertically so that y = 0 is at the top of the screen and a higher y value is closer to the bottom? It is really confusing trying to use Pyglet's flipped coordinate system with Ogmo Editor.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the maximum height of the window for your calculations:

When setting:

```
py_Y_Value = max_Screen_Height - my_Y_Value
```

or when getting:

```
my_Y_Value = max_Screen_Height - py_Y_Value
```

The best way to utilize these would be to abstract away their use in wrapper functions.